# ASP.Net MVC HttpCompileException although I removed the windows updates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a web AWS EC2 instance and in last 2 months I started getting this exception:

> Error: System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): External
>   component has thrown an exception

So I recycled the pool and this error appeared to be fixed, but a few days later it occurred again. Then I deleted the 2 Windows updates that cause this exception: `3098779`, `3097997` and then I rebooted the instance. My .NET Framework version is 4.5.2.

This exception still occurs sometimes and I have no idea how can I fix it.

Could you advise me what to do for fixing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know which external component throws the exception, and what exactly the exception is?

Comment: @LarsKristensen Everytime it throws from another component.
I think it does not related to code. It related to windows updates/.NET framework version...

Comment: Yes, but can you see what the exception is? Try inspecting the `InnerException` property of the exception you see. Also, if you suspect the issue is not related to code/programming, then there may be a better chance of getting a useful answer on another QA-site, for example on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this might help

( A crash dump should be enough to tell what is the cause of the exception,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580960)

Whole thread - https://forums.iis.net/t/1196792.aspx